# Vuex mutation mutate is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

**state.js:**

```
export default () => ({
  stepBarItems: [
    {
      title: 'General Info',
      active: false,
      current: false
    },
    {
      title: 'Personal Details',
      active: false,
      current: false
    },
    {
      title: 'Travel Details',
      active: false,
      current: false
    },
    {
      title: 'Payment',
      active: false,
      current: false
    },
    {
      title: 'Upload Documents',
      active: false,
      current: false
    }
  ]
})
```

**mutations.js:**

```
export default {
  setCurrentStepBarItem(state) {
    const index = state.stepLevel - 1
    state.stepBarItems[index].active = true
    state.stepBarItems[index].current = true
  }
}
```

**form.vue**

```
  created() {
    this.$store.commit('visa/setCurrentStepBarItem')
  },
```

the problem is that mutation is not reactive.

[image]

[image]

as you see, state is changed and i use getter to get stepBarItems,but no things changed.
what is the problem?

Comment: You dont really need these active/current variables for every bar item if you use `stepLevel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont realy need these active/current variables.
I made example for using computed properties to get desired format

```js
new Vue({
el: "#app",

data: () => ({
    stepBarItems: [
        'General Info',
        'Personal Details',
        'Travel Details',
        'Payment',
        'Upload Documents'
    ],
        stepLevel: 0
}),

computed: {
    computedStepBarItems() {
        return this.stepBarItems.map((item, index) => ({
            title: item,
            current: this.stepLevel === index,
            active: this.stepLevel >= index
        }))
    }
},

methods: {
    next() {
        this.stepLevel += 1
    },

    prev() {
        this.stepLevel -= 1
    }
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{ computedStepBarItems }}</pre>
  <button @click="prev()">Prev</button>
  <button @click="next()">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: if stepLevel = 2, the third item should be the current = true, and previous items and third once should be active = true.

Comment: slightly adjusted to your needs, mark this answer as correct

Comment: i shouldn't use vuex for this example?

Comment: you can convert it to vuex easily - make `stepLevel` as `state` property and convert `methods` to `actions`. But you should decide if you really need that